# I want to change text with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I want to provide all my posts on my blog in 2 languages. I found a way to change the text into another language with buttons. But I can't put any images or other css styles in the text that changes. Then the buttons don't work anymore.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='This is the default text. I can't put any css or html in here';">English</button> &#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='Text changed into Another language';">Other language</button>

<div id="chgtext">This is the default text. I can't put any css or html in here</div>
```

Is there a way I can make something like this but with a code where I'm able to put images, font styles,... in the code?.

Or is there maybe a way to only change the text. And leave the images with multiple divs?

TEXT (changes)

IMAGE

TEXT (changes)

http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/2017/01/17/current-favorites-voorbeeld/ --> this is an example of a post i want in 2 languages. I need multiple images, al the text in the post needs to be changed from one language to another, with buttons

Comment: something went wrong with copying the code here. On my blog the buttons do work

Comment: it's bacause you put quote inside the text (within the word `can't`) `innerHTML='This is the default text. I can't put any css or html in here'`. To prevent error you need to escape the quote: ...I can\'t...

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own using this simple code, it simply gets an entry and replace it by it's value in the array. Ex :

```
var lang = {
    "helloWorld": {
        en: "Hello World",
        fr: "Bonjour monde"
    },
    "mynameis": {
        en: "My name is",
        fr: "Mon nom est"
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(body).find('.trn').each(function($elem){
        var currentLang = 'en';
        $($elem).html(lang[$($elem).data('trn')][currentLang]);
    });
 });
```

For each text your need to add a data with the key and a class `trn`, just like this.

```
<span class="trn" data-trn="mynameis"></span> Nicolas
```

Check [this link](https://github.com/tinoni/translate.js) for more informations

hopes it helps !

- Nic

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quote in the text of the first onclick "can't" which is causing the javascript to think that it is the end of the string.
You need to add a backslash "can\'t"

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='<p>Blue</p>This is the default text. I can\'t put any css or html in here';">English</button>&#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='<p>Blue</p>Text changed into Another language';">Other language</button>

<div id="chgtext"><p>Blue</p>This is the default text. I can't put any css or html in here</div>

<style>
p {color:blue;}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not so advanced in HTML, I only know basic things for borders, hovers, images,... I can't use your code because I only get 1 text box where I can write my post. All the code that I need for 1 post needs to go in 1 Code box. so I can't use "div ... {....."

Comment: I just updated the code snippet to show you how to add HTML tags and styles

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all the children of your element. Using JQuery, and assuming just one level of descendants, you could use something like this...

```
$('#chgtxt').children().each( function() {
   var oldtext = $(this).text();
   if (oldtext) {
     var newtext = oldtext+" CHANGED. ";
     $(this).text(newtext);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all quotes inside of inserted content. Have a look at snippet and try to click on buttons

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='This is the default text. <img src=\'http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-50-50-6.jpg\'> NOW I can put any css or <span style=\'color :red;\'>html</span> in here';">English</button> &#160; 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='Text changed into Another <span style=\'color :red;\'>language</span>';">Other language</button>

<div id="chgtext">This is the default text. I can't put any css or html in here</div>
```

```html
<p>
<style>
#eng_lang {
  display: block;
}
#nl_lang {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<button onclick=" document.getElementById('eng_lang').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('nl_lang').style.display='none'">English</button> &#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('eng_lang').style.display='none';document.getElementById('nl_lang').style.display='block'">Nederlands</button></p>
<div id="eng_lang">
  <h2>Here is some text 
    <span style="color: green;">english</span>
  </h2>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo2yKPonCY-BZrk9s69oH_-gal_yxDRgHxdyXhqP79D0YESVuB" width="120px" height="120px">
     Now you can place here any text, tags and images.
</div>
<div id="nl_lang">
  <h2>Here is another text 
    <span style="color: blue;">Netherlands</span>
  </h2>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcE1c0chXugmq_V5qwp51ffAuP7ecGMsWmshnntwAXVGUgVptH" width="100px" height="100px">
  Put here whatever you want. 
  <p>This is paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, the thing is, when I insert this exact code in my post, this is what I get --> http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/2017/02/03/test/

Comment: I've added one more snippet. I think that is better solution. You can make 2 boxes: 1st comes with english text, 2nd comes with netherland. And buttons just switch display property of boxes.